# web api 2 help erroring out

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.HelpPage v5.2.4 installed for my Web API 2 app but when I load the /help page for my API I get the following error:

> System.MissingMethodException: 'Method not found: 'System.Net.Http.HttpMethod System.Web.Http.Description.ApiDescription.get_HttpMethod()'.'

Any idea what the problem might be or how to debug?

Comment: This may help: WebHttpBehavior.HelpEnabled https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.webhttpbehavior.helpenabled(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Oswald - I think the url you posted is specific to wcf, right?.  this is web api 2